# Function in a board game with chests and bandits

Tags: python, game

This function is part of a python board game program. The game is a board game with chests and bandits hidden throughout the board. The function is dedicated to the "easy" section of the game (where it is a 8x8 grid).

```
def easy_level(Coins):
#This function is for the movement of the game in easy difficulty
    while  True:
        oldcurrent=current
        boardeasy[oldcurrent[0]][oldcurrent[1]]='*' 
        table_game_easy()
        boardeasy[oldcurrent[0]][oldcurrent[1]]=' '

        n = input('Enter the direction followed by the number Ex:Up 5 , Number should be < 8 \n')
        n=n.split()
        if n[0].lower() not in ['up','left','down','right']:#Validates input
            print('Wrong command, please input again')
            continue
        elif n[0].lower()=='up':
            up(int(n[1].lower()),8)#Boundary is set to 8 as the 'easy' grid is a 8^8
        elif n[0].lower()=='down':
            down(int(n[1].lower()),8)
        elif n[0].lower()=='left':
            left(int(n[1].lower()),8)
        elif n[0].lower()=='right':
            right(int(n[1].lower()),8)

        print("5 chests left")
        print("8 bandits left")
        print("Coins:",Coins)#Acts as a counter, displays the number of coins that the player has
        if current[0] == Treasure1_Row and current[1] == Treasure1_Col\
           or current[0] == Treasure2_Row and current[1] == Treasure2_Col\
           or current[0] == Treasure3_Row and current[1] == Treasure3_Col\
           or current[0] == Treasure4_Row and current[1] == Treasure4_Col\
           or current[0] == Treasure5_Row and current[1] == Treasure5_Col\
           or current[0] == Treasure6_Row and current[1] == Treasure6_Col\
           or current[0] == Treasure7_Row and current[1] == Treasure7_Col\
           or current[0] == Treasure8_Row and current[1] == Treasure8_Col\
           or current[0] == Treasure9_Row and current[1] == Treasure9_Col\
           or current[0] == Treasure10_Row and current[1] == Treasure10_Col:
            print("Hooray! You have found booty! +10 gold")
            Coins = Coins+10 #Adds an additional 10 points
            print("Coins:",Coins)

        if current[0] == Bandit1_Row and current[1] == Bandit1_Col\
             or current[0] == Bandit2_Row and current[1] == Bandit2_Col\
             or current[0] == Bandit3_Row and current[1] == Bandit3_Col\
             or current[0] == Bandit4_Row and current[1] == Bandit4_Col\
             or current[0] == Bandit5_Row and current[1] == Bandit5_Col:
            print("Oh no! You have landed on a bandit...they steal all your coins!")
            Coins = Coins-Coins #Removes all coins
            print("Coins:",Coins)

        boardeasy[current[0]][current[1]]='*'#sets value to players position
```

Comment: what do you mean more efficient?

Comment: Reduce the amount of code needed perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

We're definitely missing some context here to run your code or understand what it is supposed to do, but there is enough to detect a few things that could be easily improved.

---

```
        Coins = Coins-Coins #Removes all coins
```

This should be:

```
        Coins = 0  #Removes all coins
```

Also

```
        Coins = Coins+10 #Adds an additional 10 points
```

can be written

```
        Coins += 10  #Adds an additional 10 points
```

---

Don't perform the same operations more than needed. In particular when handling the user input, you can limit the number of index accesses, to call to `lower` function, to call to `int` function:

```
    user_input = input('Enter the direction followed by the number Ex:Up 5 , Number should be < 8 \n').split()
    if len(user_input) != 2:
        print('Wrong command, please input again')
        continue
    direct, number = user_input
    direct = direct.lower()
    number = int(number.lower())
    if direct not in ['up','left','down','right']:#Validates input
        print('Wrong command, please input again')
        continue
    elif direct == 'up':
        up(number, 8)  #Boundary is set to 8 as the 'easy' grid is a 8^8
    elif direct == 'down':
        down(number, 8)
    elif direct == 'left':
        left(number, 8)
    elif direct == 'right':
        right(number, 8)
```

Then, you can actually change the condition order so that you don't need to list twice the valid directions:

```
    if direct == 'up':
        up(number, 8)  #Boundary is set to 8 as the 'easy' grid is a 8^8
    elif direct == 'down':
        down(number, 8)
    elif direct == 'left':
        left(number, 8)
    elif direct == 'right':
        right(number, 8)
    else:
        print('Wrong command, please input again')
        continue
```

---

You could probably rewrite the comparisons to have something like:

```
    if current == Treasure1_Pos\
       or current == Treasure2_Pos\
       or current == Treasure3_Pos\
       or current == Treasure4_Pos\
       or current == Treasure5_Pos\
       or current == Treasure6_Pos\
       or current == Treasure7_Pos\
       or current == Treasure8_Pos\
       or current == Treasure9_Pos\
       or current == Treasure10_Pos:
        print("Hooray! You have found booty! +10 gold")
        Coins += 10  #Adds an additional 10 points
        print("Coins:",Coins)

    if current == Bandit1_Pos\
         or current == Bandit2_Pos\
         or current == Bandit3_Pos\
         or current == Bandit4_Pos\
         or current == Bandit5_Pos:
        print("Oh no! You have landed on a bandit...they steal all your coins!")
        Coins = 0  #Removes all coins
        print("Coins:",Coins)
```

And you could even define a data structure (list, set) to hold all the relevant positions and write something like:

```
    if current in Treasure_Positions:
        print("Hooray! You have found booty! +10 gold")
        Coins += 10  #Adds an additional 10 points
        print("Coins:",Coins)

    if current in Bandit_Positions:
        print("Oh no! You have landed on a bandit...they steal all your coins!")
        Coins = 0  #Removes all coins
        print("Coins:",Coins)
```

---

Then more things look wrong/improvable about `boardeasy` but we'd need to see what it does.